# React window.addeventlistener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I am trying to add spotify authentication to the single page application.

Here is my button click handler event.

```
 var CLIENT_ID = '****';
  var REDIRECT_URI = window.location.href;
  function getLoginURL(scopes) {
    return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
      '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
      '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
      '&response_type=token';
  }
  var url = getLoginURL([
    'user-read-email',
    'user-read-birthdate',
    'user-read-private',
    'user-library-modify',
    'user-library-read',
    'user-follow-read',
    'user-follow-modify',
    'streaming',
    'playlist-modify-private',
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-read-collaborative',
    'playlist-read-private'
  ]);

  var width = 450,
    height = 730,
    left = (window.screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
    top = (window.screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);


  window.open(url,
    'Spotify',
    'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
  );

  console.log("window is open");

  });
```

When authentication is performed should will work window.addEventListener('message')

Here is event listener:

```
 componentDidMount() {
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  ***console.log("Spotify Window sent event data.");
  var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
    console.log(hash.access_token);
  }
}); }
```

But it doesn't work. Where is the problem in here? The section marked with *** doesn't even work.

By the way I used this documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/62wafrm7/

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: So, the event is not triggered.

Comment: I don't see anything triggering that event.

Comment: It has to work, did you see that documentation. 
http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/62wafrm7/
 
This documentation anda my code are almost the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible that, because Spotify is redirecting back to your page, the event is being fired before the component is mounted, which would mean the window isn't listening for it.

I would consider moving your `window.addEventListener()` code into your index.js file outside of any components.

Comment: Great idea, i couldn't think of that. 

I tried like you said. Now i can see all facebook Api process but Spotify doesn't affect.

What can i do that more?